# How to filter array by the value of objects' field of nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. Each object contains another array. 
How do I filter `aParticipants` array by the values of `sFullName` of nested `aParticipants` array?

```
const filterString = '';
const aParticipants = [{
    'iRoleId': 1,
    'aParticipants': [{
      'iId': 1,
      'sFullName': 'Jimmy'
    }]
  },
  {
    'iRoleId': 2,
    'aParticipants': [{
        'iId': 2,
        'sFullName': 'Tomas'
      },
      {
        'iId': 3,
        'sFullName': 'Stanley'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried this approach:

```
const aFilteredParticipants = [...aParticipants].filter(employeeBlock => {
employeeBlock.aParticipants = employeeBlock.aParticipants.filter( item => 
{
return item.sFullName.toLowerCase().includes(filterString.toLowerCase());
});
return employeesBlock.aParticipants.length;
}
```

Here I filter parent array by the length of what is left after filtering nested array. And nested array I am filtering by checking, if the field `sFullName` includes `filterString` in it.

The output is correct after first filtering. But after first filtering nested arrays `aParticipants` in objects of parent array `aParticipants` change their values to `[]` empty arrays.
Though I'm copying initial array by using spread operator.

Comment: Is it you want to filter the array without affected the original array?

Comment: @xwlee yes, that is the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const aFilteredParticipants = [...aParticipants].filter(employeeBlock

You don't need to `[...aParticipants]` **aParticipants** is already an array so it won't make any difference.

You can use the below

```js
const filterString = 'Jimmy';
const aParticipants = [{
    'iRoleId': 1,
    'aParticipants': [{
      'iId': 1,
      'sFullName': 'Jimmy'
    }]
  },
  {
    'iRoleId': 2,
    'aParticipants': [{
        'iId': 2,
        'sFullName': 'Tomas'
      },
      {
        'iId': 3,
        'sFullName': 'Stanley'
      }
    ]
  }
]

filteredParticipants = aParticipants.filter( x => {
  var isValid = false;

  [].concat(x.aParticipants).some(z => {
    if (z.sFullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      isValid = true;
    }

    return isValid;
  })

  return isValid;
})
console.log(filteredParticipants)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterString = '';

const aParticipants = [{
    'iRoleId': 1,
    'aParticipants': [{
      'iId': 1,
      'sFullName': 'Jimmy'
    }]
  },
  {
    'iRoleId': 2,
    'aParticipants': [{
        'iId': 2,
        'sFullName': 'Tomas'
      },
      {
        'iId': 3,
        'sFullName': 'Stanley'
      }
    ]
  }
]

// here we are checking that a sFullName contains our filter
const fullNameContains = filter => participant =>
  participant.sFullName.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
  
// here we verify that at least one of the aParticipants sub array contains the filter
const hasFullNames = filter => employeeBlock =>
  employeeBlock.aParticipants.some(fullNameContains(filterString))

// here we filter participants
const aFilteredParticipants = aParticipants.filter(hasFullNames(filterString))

console.log('aFilteredParticipants', aFilteredParticipants);
```